# Is there any way to minify .ejs files with grunt.js?

Tags: gruntjs, minify, ejs

The only way that I found was convert .ejs file to .html and after convert the.html to .ejs, is this right?

Comment: Why do you want to minify your EJS?

Comment: This is an exercise proposed by my instructor, I think this can improve the performance.